# Basic math always rounding down in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for my computer science class and I was having an issue with an equation. It wasn't until I started breaking the code up until I realized that all my doubles are being rounded down. For instance:

```
public static void test(){
    double var = 4/3;
    System.out.println(var);
}
```

This will print "1.0" to the console. I have commented out everything else in my code aside from the main method, which only calls this. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing integer division in Java, which must always result in another `int`, even if later assigned to a `double`.

To force floating-point division, use `double` literals:

```
double var = 4.0/3.0;
```

Only one needs to have the `.0` on it.  Or, you can cast one of them to a `double` to the same effect:

```
double var = (double) 4 / 3;
```

Another option: Place a `d` suffix on one or both literals:

```
double var = 4d / 3d;
```